Second order BDF (Backward Derivative Formula)
Note: I do not have a mathematics background, I am a PLC programmer. My understanding of calculus is the fundamentals only.
Pre-amble: I have a specific goal I am working toward. In my PLC program I have to parse an array of high resolution X,Y coordinates describing a curved line with straight segments and curved segments. The curved segments will follow a circular arc (non-elliptical). My goal is to identify the straight segments and curved segments, their start X,Y point and end X,Y point. I am attempting to identify the segments using first and second derivatives (once I identify the curved segment I'll use the start, middle and end points to calculate the arc). I wrote a function to perform the BDF method (inspiration was taken from here: link ), and initial testing has moderate results, but I'm unsure if I'm implementing it correctly. Also, if the BDF method isn't the best method, I'm happy to try other implementations as well.
Question: I am using Backward Differential Formula to approximate the differential of a curve, implemented as:

For the first order differential, I use the formula and substitute values such that $f(t_n) = y_t$ and $t_n = x_t$, where x and y are taken from my array of measured values. This works pretty well (I verified this by testing on a slightly noisy straight line the result is 1 +/- 0.1).
For the second order differential, I just use the same function again and substitute the result from the first derivative instead of $y_t$. I have no idea if this is correct, but it seems to work.
I then use these to approximate the radius of the curve using
$$R = \frac{(1-f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}{|f''(x)|}$$
I did some testing by passing in an arc with radius 1 (with a small amount of random noise due to real life measurements), and the calculated radius falls close to 1 +/- 0.5 about 50% of the time, but it also gives values as large as 50 and as small as 0.05 in places. Is this just a consequence of the noise and the solution is to improve the smoothing on the differential somehow (suggestions on methods appreciated), or am I completely off on my implementation?
An additional note, there is no pre-defined spacing of X,Y where the data is captured, the points will have different spacing between intervals.
Thanks in advance!
